# Objective-c function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, ios7

I'm trying to create a function in order to save some code, however I have no idea how I should do it.

```
if (count > 100 && count < 120)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!"
                                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You're really good at this! You scored %i points", count - 1]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    else if(count > 120)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!"
                                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEACH ME MASTER, YOU'RE A GOD! You scored %i points", count - 1]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert2 show];
    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert3 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not very good, you scored %i points", count - 1]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert3 show];
    }
```

As you can see the code is very repetitive and I would like to create a function where I can change the value of the "alert" variable and the message string. So when I call the function I only enter the functions name and the value the alert variable should have, in this case; 1, 2 and 3 and the message text depending on what condition we are looking at.

So is there some way of doing this? There has to be, because repetitive code like this is never  good looking! I would appreciate if someone could help me out, I've tried looking at some references but none of them made me get any closer to solving the problem.

Comment: you are not handling the situation well if the `count == 120`. you should do something like this: `if (count < 100) { ... } else if (count < 120) { ... } else { ... }`, which would be a less ambiguous way to handle the three branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply look at the duplicated functionality and examine the values that are *different*.  In this case it's just the message:

```
NSString *message = nil;
if (count > 100 && count < 120)
{
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You're really good at this! You scored %i points", count - 1];
}
else if(count >= 120)
{
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEACH ME MASTER, YOU'RE A GOD! You scored %i points", count - 1];
}
else
{
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not very good, you scored %i points", count - 1];
}

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!"
                                                message:message
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

(Edit: You missed the value `120` which would have slipped through the cracks).

Comment: Thanks, both solutions work great. Trojan's solution was the best though. I was stupid enough to think I had to change the variables name.

Answer (score 0):

I am create a new function that creates a new alert with given message :

```
-(void)showAlertWithMsg:(NSString *)msg tag:(NSInteger)tag
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!"
                                                message:msg
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.tag = tag;
[alert show];

}
```

To call this function write the below code:

```
 if (count > 100 && count < 120)
{
[self showAlertWithMsg:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You're really good at this! You scored %i points", count - 1] tag:1];
}
else if(count > 120)
{
    [self showAlertWithMsg:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEACH ME MASTER, YOU'RE A GOD! You scored %i points", count - 1] tag:2];
}
else
{
    [self showAlertWithMsg:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not very good, you scored %i points", count - 1] tag:3];

}
```

One more thing I am also pass the tag.So if you want to perform different operation for different alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can set "title" property exactly for existing UIAlertView instance:

```
UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView allow] init...];
alertView.title = @"Some message here.";
```